# Add depot_tools to the start of your PATH (must be ahead of any installs of Python and or git)

Tags: python, git, visual-studio, environment-variables, chromium

what does ahead of any installs of python or git mean? does it mean something like making a copy of the git files to a new folder at the end of "C:\src\depot_tools\"?

Comment: Hi Mack, if you search for the exact title of your question, you can find many pages that continue on to explain exactly how to do what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

`PATH` is the environment variable consisting of directories searched for program names. “Ahead of” usually means before; i.e., the directory where `depot_tools` is should be earlier on `PATH` (more to the left) than any python or git. (Why? I have no idea... I’m not familiar with the tool.)